# Lua: Returning rainbow text without adjacent repeats

Tags: function, lua

I'm having a bit of difficulty sussing out why the function below isn't producing the results I need. The first function produces results, but not in the manner I expect it to. The second function produces a result, but it's not working in the manner of the first function.

What I'm trying to do is return a string with random color codes injected to produce a "rainbow" of text. In the past, I was able to do this with xterm, so I thought to modify my original function to suit my current needs. Here are the functions I've tried, and their results.

```
function rbow(text)
    local colorTable = {"@w", "@b", "@r", "@g", "@y", "@c", "@m", "@W", "@B", "@R", "@G", "@Y", "@C", "@M", "@D"}

    local rcolor, sbyte, lastColor, rtext = 0, 1, 0, ""

    for i = 1, #text do
        local tempTable = {}
        for _,v in ipairs(colorTable) do
            table.insert(tempTable, v)
        end

        if i > 1 then
            table.remove(tempTable, rcolor)
        end

        math.randomseed(os.time() * string.byte(rcolor) * sbyte)
        sbyte = string.byte(i)
        rcolor = math.random(1, #tempTable)
        rtext = rtext .. tempTable[rcolor] .. text:sub(i,i)
    end

    return rtext
end

function rbow2(text)
    local colorTable = {"@w", "@b", "@r", "@g", "@y", "@c", "@m", "@W", "@B", "@R", "@G", "@Y", "@C", "@M", "@D"}
    local rcolor, lastColor, sbyte, rtext = 0, 0, 1, ""

    for i = 1, #text do
        math.randomseed(os.time() * string.byte(rcolor) * sbyte)
        sbyte = string.byte(i)
        rcolor = math.random(1, #colorTable)

        local colorCheck = function()
            if rcolor ~= lastColor then
                rtext = rtext .. tempTable[rcolor] .. text:sub(i,i)
            else
                rcolor = math.random(1, #colorTable)
                colorCheck()
            end
        end
    end

    return rtext
end

print(rbow("This is a long string to see if there are any repeated colors of letters adjacent to each other."))

> @bT@Gh@Gi@ys@Y @gi@Cs@D @ya@C @wl@bo@bn@bg@b @bs@bt@br@bi@bn@Gg@G @Gt@Go@G @Gs@Ge@Ge@G @Gi@yf@B @ct@Mh@ye@Br@ce@M @ya@Br@Be@B @Ba@Bn@By@B @Br@Be@Bp@Be@Ga@gt@Ye@gd@Y @gc@Yo@gl@Yo@gr@Cs@b @co@gf@C @bl@ce@gt@Ct@be@Rr@Ys@D @Da@Dd@Dj@Da@Dc@De@Dn@yt@G @yt@Go@y @Ge@ya@Gc@yh@G @yo@Ct@yh@Ce@yr@C.


 print(rbow2("This is a long string to see if there are any repeated colors of letters adjacent to each other."))

> 0
```

In the first example, adjacent letters are being represented by the same color code, for example:

```
@bo@bn@bg@b @bs@bt@br@bi@bn -- all @b
@G @Gt@Go@G @Gs@Ge@Ge@G @Gi -- all @G
```

and so forth. The odd factor is that the same pattern (with different color codes) pretty much repeats on subsequent returns. It doesn't match exactly, but in three prints, "to see" and "adjacent" carried the same color code throughout the words.

I'm unsure how to proceed with this. I do NOT want it to repeat colors in adjacent letters, and I'd have thought the first function would take care of that, removing the recently used color code from the tempTable. What am I missing?

Comment: `math.randomseed` should be moved out of the loop

Comment: `sbyte = string.byte(i)` gives ASCII code of the first character of `tostring(i)`

Comment: `local colorCheck = function()` is a wrong way to define recursive function

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I had `math.randomseed` in the loop to fully maximize randomness (hence why it multiplies by two other factors). And not sure then how to do a recursive function and retaining the values, hmm.